# What is the interval for $θ$ to get a butterfly curve?

Tags: calculus

$$r= e^{\cosθ} -2\cos4θ + \sin^3 \fracθ4$$
What will be the shortest interval for θ in order to get a butterfly curve?

Comment: May I know how to get it?